# Why my date is not parsing

Tags: java, datetime

```
private final SimpleDateFormat gmailDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

But when i parse the date String "Thu, 25 Sep 2014 16:26:20 +0300" i get the following exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 25 Sep 2014 16:26:20 +0300"
```

Comment: private final SimpleDateFormat gmailDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'");

Comment: What version of Java are you using, works fine me with Java 7

Comment: Sorry, was using Java 7 also :P - works okay in Java 6 as well...problems not with the format, the problem might be with the `String`

Comment: @getlost, you solution did nto work, but any way thankx.. i have seen your suggestin in many places. Seems like a java version problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the Locale.ENGLISHas second parameter to the SimpleDateFormat constructor and it works:

```
private static  final SimpleDateFormat gmailDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Date formatter is working fine. Make sure you are importing right package. See below the complete program

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String ap[])
    {
        SimpleDateFormat gmailDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        try {
            java.util.Date date = gmailDateFormatter.parse("Thu, 25 Sep 2014 16:26:20 +0300");
            System.out.println(date); 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thu Sep 25 06:26:20 PDT 2014
```

Comment: The imports were fine. But the same application worked in linux environment with open jdk. But in windows it didnt.